# How can I quickly gather page views for different page paths?

Tags: google-analytics

I'd like to gather page views for a given number of page paths on the same period, but I can't figure out how to do this in Google Analytics...

My website is multilingual and share the same GA ID, so basically I have pages like `/contact`, `/de/kontact`or `/fr/contact`and I'd like get the page views of these pages without having to use the filter for every path, and then add ever number manually...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I suggest to filter out the language path prefixes. Apart from the fact that there's little value in tracking page views (different topic) there's no point in differentiating translations viewed. There's better ways to do that  (Audience>Geo>Language) so imo the language path is just in the way.

Add a "Search and replace" on "Request URI" filter replacing

```
^/(en|de|fr)/
```

(including all languages you might have) with simply

```
/
```

#### Use Content Groups

Content groups are a great way to slice your site in arbitrary pieces. Create a Content Group (you can only have 5) and add every part of your page you want to see grouped together as a "Rule definition" group. Try to cover all areas of your page, since all pages which are not covered by a rule will end up in a `(not set)` group.

For `contact` create a rule set

```
Page starts with: /contact
OR
Page starts with`: /kontakt
```

You would have to add each language separately if there is no common part across them you could use to combine them (like an id which is shared by all "Contact" pages). Alternatively, track a `virtual page` view which do not use the translated terms in the path.